# How do I combine the results of IEnumerable and IRanked?

Tags: c#

How do I combine allResults into filteredDownResults? For background I am using using NinjaNye.SearchExtensions.  Please ask if you need more info.  Greatful for any input.

```
IEnumerable<proc_GetAllQuestions_Result> allResults = context.proc_GetAllQuestions(85).ToArray();
IRanked<proc_GetAllQuestions_Result>[] filteredDownResults = null;
filteredDownResults = allResults.Where(x => x.QuestionText == "marshmellows").ToArray();  //This doesn't work.

public interface IRanked<out T>
{
    int Hits { get; }
    T Item { get; }
}

public partial class proc_GetAllQuestions_Result
{
    public int Rank { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> RowID { get; set; }
    public int PK_QuestionID { get; set; }
    public int PK_ProgramID { get; set; }
    public string ProgramName { get; set; }
    public string FK_AgencyID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ApprovedDateTime { get; set; }
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }
    public string FinalAnswer { get; set; }
    public string FK_SearchKeywords { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedFinalAnswer { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Archive { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> FK_ProgramID { get; set; }
    public int ProgramAreaID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are facing? Unexpected empty result? Exception?

Comment: if you could show what the result you want, we could better understand ...

Comment: Thanks so far, The error I'm getting is this...Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'Dhs.PolicyQuest.UI.proc_GetAllQuestions_Result[]' to 'NinjaNye.SearchExtensions.Models.IRanked<Dhs.PolicyQuest.UI.proc_GetAllQuestions_Result>[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 0):

if i have understood your problem, what i could see of your coding you dont use your interface IRanked, you have to send your result to your Interface

```
var filteredDownResults = allResults.Search(x => x.QuestionText)
                                    .IsEqual("marshmellows")
                                    .ToRanked();
```